# npm install grunt-uncss and npm install grunt uncss

Tags: npm, gruntjs, uncss

pretty new to grunt and just trying to use uncss. Notice their is 2 way to install it with npm: 
npm install uncss --save-dev and
 npm install grunt-uncss --save-dev.

Besides one using phantom.js is their any difference ?? Pretty confused here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a little info, one's designed to be used independent of workflow, while one is designed to be used in a [Grunt](https://npmjs.com/package/grunt)-based workflow. Typically, things starting with grunt-, or [gulp](https://npmjs.com/package/gulp)- are wrappers around existing packages, or perform specific functions within the specified workflow with little to no additional wrapper code required. Whereas the normal package, which is probably a dependency of grunt-uncss would require some wrapper code to function properly in a grunt-based workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Those are actually for two different packages:

- `npm install uncss --save-dev` is for the uncss npm package.
- `npm install grunt-uncss --save-dev` is for the grunt plugin for uncss

**The difference between the two**

One you can use with Grunt.js (grunt-uncss), the other you can't (without writing your own task that calls the module)